# How to get id or name of an element of flash website using selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

When right click from mozilla browser i dont get 'Inspect element' option.
instead it give me adobe settings.

How can i automate this using selenium-rc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can handle Flex elements by using sikuli, we can download it from the below path:

> www.launchpad.net/sikuli/+download.

Comment: Can i use sikuli with selenium-rc...?

Comment: When i right click get below 4 option but i don't get the option "Inspect element (Q)" to get the id.                               1.Print 2.Settings 3.Global Settings 4.About Adobe Flash Player

Comment: Flash-Selnium  is good or  sikuli . Which i can use for my project.

Comment: For the Flex elements you will not inspect Element(Q) options. You will get the options wt u have mentioned. Sikuli is the best. you can capture screenshots and use.

Comment: Thanks, Mickey. I have tried Sikuli it is great, it has resolved my problem. Thanks.